# php using preg_replace to replace dot

Tags: php

I want to extend my current preg_replace code and also replace all dots (.).

How can I extend my code, everything I try does not work.

```
<?php $optiontitleok = preg_replace('/(\s|&(amp;)?)+/', '', $optiontitle);?>
```

Comment: what $optiontitle contains?

Comment: @Chudilka It contains multiple values, including multiple signs. I just want to replace all spaces, + signs, dots etc. So I need to extend my current code.

Comment: The current regex does not seem to replace plus-signs though? You have added the plus-sign at the end of your group, which means that you search for a minimum of one occurence of your group.

Comment: Oh, sry, i didn't see your Rep @HenkZ, I thought this was your first question, never mind :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are searching for whitespace-characters OR ampersands, the below pattern also includes a check for periods (whitespace OR ampersands OR dots):

```
<?php $optiontitleok = preg_replace('/(\s|&(amp;)?|\.)+/', '', $optiontitle);?>
```

When in doubt building your regex, this site is a goldmine:

https://regex101.com

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

As I stated in the comments I don't believe you are testing for and replacing the "+" signs. You're using it as a quantyfier at the end of your group. To replace whitespace, ampersands, plus-signs and periods, you could use the following pattern:

```
\s|\&|\.|\+
```

Result:

```
<?php $optiontitleok = preg_replace('/\s|\&|\.|\+/', '', $optiontitle);?>
```

Comment: Awesome! :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete all except alphabet and digits, you can use next code:

```
$optiontitle= "test.test.test+#   @df344";
$optiontitleok = preg_replace('/[^\d\w]+/', '', $optiontitle);
echo $optiontitleok;
```

output is:

> testtesttestdf344